# Are there some decisive ways of signaling an answer to somebody else's question as definitive?

Tags: discussion, answers

Beside commenting and voting are there some other means to signal an answer as definitive when the author did not mark it so?

There are some older questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/67432/47206) that are useful and actual, and which have a perfect answer that is not set as definitive.  It clearly deserves to be marked as such. Is there a level of reputation that allows that?

Comment: You can't force low rep users to accept answers.  Voting should take care of it (or asking a similar question after it appears abandoned and requesting a merge so you can accept the other answer).  The latter is a little sketchy, but might "solve" the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force low rep users to accept answers.

Voting should take care of it (or asking a similar question after it appears abandoned and requesting a merge so you can accept the other answer).

The latter is a little sketchy, but might "solve" the problem.

Comment: “requesting a merge” Interesting, I wasn't even aware this was possible. How can one ask this kind of merge?

Comment: Flag it with a custom flag asking a mod to do it.  Do not do that lightly though.  Mods have lots to do even before they start doing mod tasks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, award the definitive answer a [bounty](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties). You can go as low as 50 points, and the answer you prefer will have a nice orange '50' next to it.

Comment: nice one! i think i'll use this sometime!